# How to get each question_id and answer from the array?

Tags: php

If the user is doing a registration in a conference, and is registering 1 participants in the registration type with id "1" (Jake K), and 1 participant in the regitration type with id "4" (John W), the request with the form data has this 3 arrays:

```
"name" => array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    1 => "Jake"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    1 => "John"
  ]
]
"surname" => array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    1 => "K"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    1 => "W"
  ]
]
"answer" => array:1 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼   
    1 => array:2 [▼   // answers answered for the registration_type_id 1
      1 => "answer1"
      2 => "answer2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Is necessary to use the info of this array to insert in the `participants` and `answers` table. Its inserting correctly in the `participants` table but for the `answers` table is not working:

```
 foreach ($request->all()['name'] as $key => $nameArray) {
        foreach ($nameArray as $nameKey => $name) {
            // this is working
            $participant_result = Participant::create([
                'name'                 => $name,
                'surname'              => $request['surname'][$key][$nameKey],
                'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                'registration_type_id' => $key
            ]);


            // save answer to Database if exist
            // this is not working
            $answer = Answer::create([
                'question_id' => $request['answer'][$key], // the issue is here
                'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
                'answer' => $request['answer'][$key][$nameKey], // and here
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The issue is because is necessary to insert in the `question_id` and `answer` columns of the `answers` table. But this values are not returned correctly from the array with  "`$request['answer'][$key]`" and "`$request['answer'][$key][$nameKey]`".

Do you know how to properly get the question id and answer from the array?

In this above array example, the question id of the "answer1" is 1 and the id of the "answer2" is 2.

```
  "answer" => array:1 [▼
    1 => array:1 [▼
      1 => array:2 [▼
        1 => "answer1"
        2 => "answer2"
      ]
    ]
```

---

Form:

```
<form method="post"
      action="https://proj.test/conference/1/conf-test/registration/storeRegistration">
    <h6> Participant - 1 - general</h6>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="namegeneral_1">Name</label>
      <input type="text" required  id="namegeneral_1" name="name[1][1]" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="surnamegeneral_1">Surname</label>
      <input type="text"  id="surnamegeneral_1" class="form-control" name=" surname[1][1]" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="participant_question">Question 1</label>
      <input type='text' name='answer[1][1][1]' class='form-control' required>
      <input type="hidden" name="question_required[1][1]" value="1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="participant_question">Question 2</label>
      <textarea name='answer[1][1][2]' class='form-control' rows='3' required></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="question_required[1][2]" value="1">
    </div>

    <h6> Participant - 1 - plus</h6>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nameplus_1">Name</label>
      <input type="text" required  id="rnameplus_1" name="rname[4][1]" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="surnameplus_1">Surname</label>
      <input type="text"  id="rsurnameplus_1" class="form-control" name=" rsurname[4][1]" value="">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: in loop you have more than one name, but answer has one key (`1`). On second run you have `$key == 4`, but not have this in `$request['answer']`. Maybe inside first loop you shoud have two loops? One for registering participants and one for registering answers? If answers are registered for both, build array with `$participantResult` and for every answer register `count($participantResult)` answers :O If not, remember ID only for first registered participant and save answer.

Please tell me how `$request['answer']` works? What is `$request['answer'][1]` and what `$request['answer'][1][1]`?

Secondly `$request['answer'][$key][$nameKey]` in this case is array of two elements. If Answer::create knows about it - it's no problem ;)

**EDIT**

Is this right solution?

```
<?php
$aPID = [];

foreach ($request->all()['name'] as $key => $nameArray) {
    foreach ($nameArray as $nameKey => $name) {
        $aPID[$key] = Participant::create([
            'name'                 => $name,
            'surname'              => $request['surname'][$key][$nameKey],
            'registration_id' => $registration->id,
            'registration_type_id' => $key
        ]);
    }
}

foreach($request['answer'] as $pid => $answersArray) {
    foreach($answersArray as $questionId => $answer) {
        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $questionId,
            'participant_id' => $aPID[$pid],
            'answer' => $answer,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The registration type with id 4 dont have the answers array because there are no custom questions associated with the registration type with id 4 so in the registration form dont appear any custom question for the participant being registered in the registration type with id 4 and so there are no answers array for the registration type with id 4.

Comment: Man, I know what the result of `$request['answer'][1]` is but do not know what that `[1]` means? And second from `$request['answer'][1][1]`? I think that first index is reference to `['name'][1]`, but second? Can you show me how is form built?

Comment: I updated the question with that, the$request['answer'] [1] is the ansewers of the registration type that has the id 1.

Comment: I think that could be more comfortably if you have form made like this: `name="participant[1][name]"`, `name="participant[1][answer][1]` ... If this is possible ;)

Comment: Like that it shows "Array to string conversion (

SQL: insert into `answers` (`question_id`, `participant_id`, `answer`) 

values (1, {"name":"Jake","surname":"K","registration_id":207,"registration_type_id":1,"id":83}, answer1))
".

Comment: With "                    'participant_id' => $aPID[$pid]->id,
" shows "Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `answers` (`question_id`, `participant_id`, `answer`) values (1, 93, answer1))
".

Comment: OK, `Participant::create` is returning some structure, not ID what I was thinking. You must firstly get ID of this newly created participant and add this to `$aPID[$key]`. I think that this JSON string (`{"name":"Jake","surname":"K","registration_id":207,"registration_type_id":1,"id":83}`) is result of trying to convert object to string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178275/discussion-between-arczinosek-and-john).